# C# (encog) load dataset from txt file

Tags: c#, file.readalllines

I would like to build a simple neural network with ENCOG to perform classification. I found a example that shows XOR. There is a double array that contains inputs and another array that contains ideal outputs for the learning process. So the dataset looks like this:

```
 /// Input f o r the XOR f unc t i on .
 public static double [ ] [ ] XORInput = {
 new[ ] { 0.0 , 0.0 },
 new[ ] { 1.0 , 0.0 },
 new[ ] { 0.0 , 1.0 },
 new[ ] { 1.0 , 1.0}
 } ;

 /// I d e a l output f o r the XOR f unc t i on .
 public static double [ ] [ ] XORIdeal = {
 new[ ] { 0.0 } ,
 new[ ] { 1.0 } ,
 new[ ] { 1.0 } ,
 new[ ] {0.0}
 } ;

 // create training data
        IMLDataSet trainingSet = new BasicMLDataSet(XORInput, XORIdeal);
```

Then the network it self is created and here is the learning process initialized

```
 // train the neural network
        IMLTrain train = new ResilientPropagation(network, trainingSet);
```

Now I would like to know how can I load my own dataset from a txt files so I can use it instead of XORInput, XORIdeal.

I have tried:

```
 string[] ins = File.ReadAllLines(path);
 double [] inputs = new double[ins.Length]

 for(int i=0; i<ins.Length; i++)
 {
 inputs[i] = Double.Parse(ins[i]);
 }
```

EDIT: This is how my inputs looks like:

166  163  180  228
165  162  160  226
166  163  180  228
166  164  180  228
171  162  111  225

And OUT:

0 0 1

0 0 1

0 1 0

1 0 0

0 1 0

This is not working. I assume that its because I do not have every one element of txt files indexed. I am stucked here. Can anyone help please? Thank you.

Comment: Can you show a sample of the file you are trying to load?

Comment: Thanks. Is this question about the ENCOG library or the reading of an input file? If it's both, I'd recommend writing two separate questions.

Comment: For now, lets just say that I would like to load my dataset to that kind of format that will be accepted by ENCOG (double[][] array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, a quick snippet:

```
using System.Linq;

public static class Load {
    public static double[][] FromFile(string path) {
        var rows = new List<double[]>();
        foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(path)) {
            rows.Add(line.Split(new[]{' '}).Select(double.Parse).ToArray());
        }
        return rows.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Call like `XORInput = Load.FromFile("C:\\...");`
Hopefully if you pick through that it should become clear.

Comment: I tried it, but as soon as I try to call it like: public static double[][] Input = Load.FromFile("E:\vstup.txt"); I am getting error message: A object reference is required for the non-static method Load.FromFile(string). When I change the Load class to public class and in my main method I make a object reference like Load l = new Load(); and then double[][] Input = l.FromFile(@"E:\vstup.txt"); It says that Input is not in correct format and something with DateTime. What could be wrong?